Traveling with ADHD medication Lisdexamfetamine to Thailand
We are travelling to Thailand and intend to bring ADHD medication Lisdexamfetamine for a duration of 16 days.
Itinerarey is Frankfurt (FRA) - Doha - Phuket. I assume the transit in Doha is not a problem, is this correct?
I have difficulties to find out if import to Thailand is legal and if so, if it needs to be declared or a permit is required.
What I could find so far:
Information from the Thai embassy in Australia from 2015:
https://canberra.thaiembassy.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/faq-version-2015.pdf
"Lisdexamfetamine is classified as
medical preparations according to the Drug Act B.E. 2510 (1967). A patient under
treatment can carry those medications into Thailand for personal use in a quantity
NOT EXCEEDING 30 DAYS OF PRESCRIBED USAGE.
For methylphenidate and lisdexamfetamine, when you already have the required
document and prescription from the prescribing physician to accompany the
medication in question, if you have nothing else to declare you are allowed to pass
through the Green Channel at airport customs without declaring the medication
because it is then considered as personal belongings."
Here it is labelled a "Category 2" medicine.
However in the Swedish Thai embassy website https://thaiembassy.se/en/tourism/restricted-medicine/ I cannot find it on the list for narcotics in category 2 or elsewhere.
In a 2 year old reddit thread
https://www.reddit.com/r/Thailand/comments/t346xu/bringing_adhd_medication_into_thailand/
one user apparently had a similar problem and got an official reply from tnarcotics@fda.moph.go.th
I wonder if this is still up to date and reliable.
"Vyvanse is legal to bring a 30 day script with you. You can email the Thai FDA (tnarcotics@fda.moph.go.th) yourself to confirm, but here is the response they'll send. I received it on Feb 17, 2022. I understand this is a 4 month old post, but posting this here to help others who come along researching the same question. Adderall and other amphetamine ADHD drugs are not allowed. Vyvanse is allowed. I guess since it is technically a prodrug. I'm not about to argue about the logical issue of it. I am still trying to figure out if you can get it prescribed and refilled in country though.

I would like to in form you that in Thailand, Lisdexamfetamine is
classified as a medical preparations according to the Drug Act B.E.
2510 (1967). So, if a patient under treatment is allowed to bring
those medications into Thailand for personal use in a quantity NOT
EXCEEDING 30 DAYS OF PRESCRIBED USAGE when accompanied by a valid
prescription and/or medical document from the prescribing physician.
Therefore, you don't need the permit for medical preparation. However,
please keep the medications in the original packaging. Please keep
prescription and/or medical document from the prescribing physician
between you stay in Thailand.

"

For a reliable and up-to-date answer if I were you I would contact the Thai embassy in Canberra and/or the official source mentioned in the Reddit thread you cite in your question.

It sounds like you've done some research and found a number of sources, all saying basically the same thing. What are your specific remaining doubts?

@Sneftel my doubts were the somewhat conflicting information between the embassy website in Sweden and Australia. With the link in the answer i was able to check that is indeed ok to carry with us. We wanted to be extra cautious since some other prescription drugs can land you in jail in Thailand and that might be rather inconvenient ;)


I have difficulties to find out if import to Thailand is legal and if so, if it needs to be declared or a permit is required.

The website of the Thailand Narcotics Control Division Food And Drug Administration allows you to search for drugs and get related information. According to this website Lisdexamfetamine is not classified as a narcotic drug or psychotropic substance and can be carried for personal use in a quantity not exceeding 30 days of prescribed usage. This information can be printed. A permit is not needed.
You should always bring the prescription or a document from your doctor along with you and keep the medication in its original packaging.

I assume the transit in Doha is not a problem, is this correct?

The Qatar Ministry of Public Health provides a guide: Guideline of Controlled Drugs for Travellers
Lisdexamfetamine is not on the list of prohibited items or narcotics.

Thanks very much!

Disclaimer: I'm neither a lawyer nor a doctor. I only access (and linked) public available information. When in doubt contact the respective embassies. If possible I'd try to leave the medication at home, but I know the struggles ADHD causes. Keep the medication in your checked luggage.

@NorthernGardenStarter, why keep meds in checked luggage? The usual advice is to keep it, or at least a part, in your carry-on. Also you usually pick up your checked luggage before customs so will have both when checked.

The thought was avoiding any issues when transiting, as the checked luggage will be forwarded by the airline. But you're right, that suggestion was a bit thoughtless, especially since luggage may get lost and you don't want to end up without your medication.

If you need to transit you need to know the laws (and how they work out for transit passengers) and having forbidden drugs in hold luggage during transits in some countries is not a good plan. Hopefully this is nowhere seen as illegal drugs.
